# next.js how to handle an #id inside an #id

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have this url i need to create to share an item. i've gotten it ideally so with the first #id of the section fine but now i need to get an id inside that section

what works so far is .../store/1#parent  but i cant understand how to get the child components id in the url the sections of the child can get lengthy so we wanna be able to scroll to the associated child link shared

```
<div id="parent">
 <ChildComponent/>
</div>
```

the component is like such

```
<div>
 <p id="child1"></p>
 <p id="child2"></p>
 <p id="child3"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: First thing, your `id` should be unique in the whole document not just the component (so, if its hardcoded like you've shown, and you're using `ChildComponent` multiple times in the same page, then that's not valid HTML). Second, URL fragments don't care if `#child1` is inside `#parent`. You just need `#child1` to link to that component.

Comment: child1, child2 child3, are not unique?

Comment: i think that means if childComponent is used more than once in the same page. this case it is only used once one the parent page.

Comment: Yeah that's what I wrote. If its not used multiple times, then URL to `child1` will be `.../store/1#child1`.

Comment: ok makes sense. thanks will try that out. so far it's still not going to the child id but it's wrapped in a headless ui component. which i think is causing the issue of not finding the id

Comment: looks like i'm good! gotta fix the ui since the divs toggle open it wont read the id. Appreciate it!